# Propagate changes to git branches and retain history

Tags: git

I am teaching someone learn to code, and prepare a dedicated git repository with many instructional branches (currently 28 of them) with detailed instructions in each branch. And each branch involve with some code that later branch will need. So if I made a mistake in earlier branch, then I need to go through all later branch to do a rebase against previous one in order to pick up the change and retain the commit history.

Suppose I made a mistake in 6th branch, what I do now is go to 7th branch, rebase against 6th branch, then go to 8th branch and repeat, all the way to 28th branch. It is quite tedious and error-prone.

I know there is a tool called https://github.com/rvagg/workshopper which powers https://github.com/jlord/git-it, but is there a Git technique which can propagate changes to later branches yet still retains commit history?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

All 28 branches are here: https://github.com/jollygoodcode/property_expert/branches/all

Comment: Are the branches all just fast-forwards of each other?

Comment: @merlin2011 Supposing they are, is there a reasonable way to accomplish this?